# sending variables to subprocess call with spaces - python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ffmpeg, subprocess

I want to add ffmpeg options to a variable and later use it in a subprocess call. If the variable contains one word, all is well, but if it contains more than one, I get errors. I am working on a larger script and I will need to have extra options such as this for certain codecs. How can I get this working?

The following works perfectly for me:

```
import subprocess
import sys

video_codec = 'libx264'
output = sys.argv[1] + '.mkv'
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg',
            '-i',sys.argv[1], 
            '-c:v',video_codec,
            '-c:a','copy',         
            output])
```

Once I introduce new options/spaces to  `video_options` as such:

```
video_codec = "'libx264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p'"
```

I get an ffmpeg error:

```
Unknown encoder ''libx264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p''
```

If I remove the double quotes and just use
    video_codec = 'libx264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p'

I get a python error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testo.py", line 10, in <module>
    output])

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just have a single string with all the options? e.g. `'libx264, -pix_fmt, yuv420p'`

Comment: In my main script, I am defining a generic ffmpeg function that I can add different variables to. i don't want to have to type out a fresh command for every use situation. As not every command will require a pix_fmt alteration, I'd rather just add that to the video_codec variable.

Comment: Use [**`shlex`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html).

Comment: Each element of the argument list is a single argument in the executable.  There is no word splitting done, so spaces are preserved exactly.  If you want to add extra options, you must add those to the argument list, not try to embed them within other arguments--or you can build a string and use `shell=True` to get the word splitting functionality back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric Renouf has it right, but don't create a string, its less reliable.  You just have to break apart your config like this:

```
video_codecs = ['libx264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p']
output = sys.argv[1] + '.mkv'
cmd_list = ['ffmpeg',
        '-i',sys.argv[1], 
        '-c:v']
cmd_list += video_codecs
cmd_list += ['-c:a','copy',         
        output]
subprocess.call(cmd_list)
```

I'm not sure if the order matters, so I preserved it here, if order doesn't matter, you can just combine the last line with the third line.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. It has the extra perk of being quite similar to what I did in bash (I'm obviously a python novice), so I'm very comfortable with this approach. Thank you so much!